# Inner product of two independently chosen Gaussian vectors is almost zero

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, normal-distribution

I am now working on an exercise problem (Ex. 2.29) from [*Foundations of Data Science*](https://home.ttic.edu/%7Eavrim/book.pdf) by A. Blum, J, Hopcroft, and R. Kannan:

> Let $x$ and $y$ be $d$-dimensional zero mean, unit variance Gaussian vectors. Prove that $x$ and $y$ are almost orthogonal by considering their dot product.

Below is my attempt:

> Inspired by [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109989/concentration-results-for-inner-products-of-two-independent-random-gaussian-vect), I let $z = x^Ty/|x|$ and concluded that $z\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and that $z$ is independent of $x$, by rotational invariance of spherical Gaussian. Then, for $\epsilon > 0$, I tried to directly compute $\mathbb{P}(|x^Ty| > \epsilon)$ by conditioning on $|x|$, i.e.,
> $$
> \mathbb{P}(|x^Ty| > \epsilon) = \int_0^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(|z| > \epsilon/r) f(r)\mathrm{d} r = \int_0^{\infty} 2[1 - \Phi(\epsilon/r)]f(r)\mathrm{d}r,
> $$
> where $f(r)$ denotes the PDF of $|x|$.

This is what I have done so far. Yet I am not sure how to proceed. I know that by the Gaussian annulus theorem, most of $|x|$ will be concentrated around the surface $\sqrt{d}\mathbb{S}^{d-1}$, but how am I supposed to bound $f(r)$ and the whole integral above? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What exactly does "almost orthogonal" mean?

Comment: @uniquesolution By "almost orthogonal" I suppose it means that for $\epsilon > 0$, $\mathbb{P}(|x^T y| > \epsilon)$ is bounded above by some function of $d$ that decays as $d\to\infty$.

Comment: This seems to be equivalent to: "A random point on $\mathbb{S}^{d}$ is near the equator."

Comment: @Semiclassical Given $y \sim \mathcal{N}(0, I_d)$, I know that most of the volume of the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^d$ concentrates around the equator, and from this I can infer that $x^Ty/|x|$ is almost 0. But how should I deal with $|x|$?

Comment: Focusing on the dot product feels like it's making things too complicated: what you care about is the angle, i.e., the value of $x^T y/(|x||y|)$. (The main reason I say this is that rescaling $x$, $y$ doesn't change the angle at all. Hence we shouldn't need to worry about $|x|$ in the first place.)